# omp.h can't be found when compile C++ with MinGW on windows

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I am writing C++ code and compile using g++, MinGM, on windows, but error shows that:

error: omp.h: No such file or directory
 #include 
                 ^
compilation terminated.

This is the installation list when i installed MinGW:
[image]

omp.h file cannot be found in installation file of MinGW:
[image]

Comment: Make sure you use `<omp.h>` (angular brackets)

Comment: Yes.  error: omp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <omp.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: Do you have `D:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\omp.h` ?

Comment: I cant find opm.h file in D:\MinGW , and of course also not in D:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the [public sources](http://docs-windows.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devel.html#mingw-with-openmp-support) recommend installing `TDM-GCC`, because it has default OpenMP installation choice:

http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download

Also, with standard `MinGW`, try from your `MinGW` console:

```
mingw-get install mingw32-pthreads-w32
mingw-get install mingw32-pthreads-w32-dev
```